# IOS Google Maps Different Custom Info Window For Each Set Of Markers

Tags: ios7, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have two different set of markers displayed on my google maps on IOS. 
I have seen many samples to show a custom info window when a marker is tapped. 
I need to show different custom info window to be shown for each set of Markers.

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker {

   // How do I identify which info window to show from GSMMarker ???

  if(marker type is 1){

          show this info window1

  }else if(marker type is 2){

          show this info window2

  }

}
```

Comment: Ended up using marker.userData.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you used this. My every marker is showing the same info.